# How to tell of transformed array should be filled at a certain index

Tags: c++, arrays

I have been given a 1D array that represents an image, each index representing 1 pixel. My goal is to scale up each pixel by a power of 2 (i.e 1px becomes 4px; scaled by a factor of 2). I am having a hard time determining how I should fill in the new array. Could someone kindly advise me on a formula/method to determine which pixel in the old array corresponds to which group of pixels in the new array?

Comment: add a language tag

Comment: @Nur added the language tag. Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing! Pixel `(x, y)` "in the old array" become pixels `(2x, 2y)-(2x+1,2y+1)` "in the new array".